# Login to PostgreSQL Failed

Tags: php, postgresql, xampp, pgadmin

I configured xampp to work with php and postgres db. I am unable to log into my postgres via localhost/phppgadmin/.

[image: postgres error]

I have read so many resources online and none has worked for me. I did all of the following:

```
$conf['extra_login_security'] = false;

# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
```

I also set the listening port to '*'. I tried re-installing postgres and I set the superuser password as postgres. This still did not work. What else can I do ?

Comment: You didn't look at the important resource: the PostgreSQL log. Did you restart PostgreSQL after changing `listen_addresses`?

Comment: What are the connection parameters for the server?

Comment: Yes @LaurenzAlbe I did restart the service after changing the listen_addresses. Where can I find the PostgreSQL log?

Comment: Look at the `log_directory` parameter, unless you are on Debian/Ubuntu, where it usually is in `/var/log/postgresql`. Connect with `psql`, that will give you a better error message.